# JSOUP HTTPStatusException 400 error

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I get the following error while connecting to the URL

`org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400`

I use the following code to connect to the URL

`doc = Jsoup.connect("https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/search.cfm?query=4-Hydroxyphenyl-Pyruvate Dioxygenase Inhibitor&searchdb=class").get();`

when I hit the URL in the browser it displays the HTML content fine.

Please suggest as to what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

URL-Encode the spaces in your URL using `%20`

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/search.cfm?query=4-Hydroxyphenyl-Pyruvate%20Dioxygenase%20Inhibitor&searchdb=class").get();
```

This issue has been fixed in version 1.7.3 of Jsoup (see [this](https://jsoup.org/news/release-1.7.3)) so you may upgrade to that version as an alternative.